# Recommended approach for storing usernames and hashed passwords in a database with .NET/WinForms

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, mysql-connector

I am working on a legacy .NET application that provides a desktop client for accessing a MySQL database. It's written in VB.NET and uses WinForms for entering data into and retrieving data from the database.

I need to extend the software to add user accounts and roles so that the client can control which users have access to the data.

This must have been common in the past, but I can't find documentation for this that is isn't part of the ASP.NET web framework and I can't see how to move forward. Is there a recommended approach in .NET for doing this?

Comment: Recommended: is not to store password at all

Comment: No, if you really have to then hash the password and then store the hash rather and not the actual password

Comment: @Rahul I've edited to say hashed passwords. If I intended to store the passwords as plain text then I wouldn't have needed to ask the question!

Comment: @Rahul if this is a duplicate then can you provide a link? (Or remove the duplicate label)

Comment: Duplicate question link already present in the dupe banner. For your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: I have heard that Bcrypt is good. I believe there is a Nuget.